# How to make dynamic background gradient in scrollView android

Tags: android

I want layout with dynamic background gradient. Start scroll from one color and at the end of scroll another color. If this screen without scroll, background looks like usual gradient.

Is there are any way to do it?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Have you written any code? Stack Overflow is not for people to just give you directions you need to be asking a specific question.

Comment: Yes i did. And it's not regular behavior, that's why i trying to get some help here

Comment: Right but we need to see what you have tried to see how to fix it. You need to post your code that you think should be making it work and ask why it doesn't rather than ask generally how to do it. Stack Overflow is not for general brainstorming. You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, then sorry for this post. I tried change RGB in onScrollChanged(), but it doesn't flexible and dont look like good decision. And i have no idea how i should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean.You can create a xml file in `drawable` and name it like `background.xml`. In this file, for example:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape = "rectangle">
        <gradient
           android:startColor="#`enter code here`"
           android:endColor="#`enter code here`"
           android:angle="..." />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </selector>
```

Then in the layout of your activity, you set background by `@drawable/background.xml`

Comment: I tried it. It's almost what i need. But, If there any way how to make this background size of whole scroll view.

Comment: Have you tried with `ScrollView` yet? I think i will work

Comment: I Just set this background to child of scrollView, oh it was so easy. Shame on me. Thank you.